# Get all possible combinations in a time-series data with variable daily readings

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a time-series dataset of daily consumption which looks like the following:

```
consumption <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2020-06-01','2020-06-02','2020-06-03','2020-06-03',
                   '2020-06-03','2020-06-04','2020-06-05','2020-06-05')),
  val = c(10,20,31,32,33,40,51,52)
)

consumption <- consumption %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(n = n(), record = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

consumption

# A tibble: 8 × 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    31     3      1
4 2020-06-03    32     3      2
5 2020-06-03    33     3      3
6 2020-06-04    40     1      1
7 2020-06-05    51     2      1
8 2020-06-05    52     2      2
```

Some days have more than one rows in the dataset. I would like to transform this into split groups with all possible combinations such as:

**Group 1:**

```
        date val record
1 2020-06-01  10      1
2 2020-06-02  20      1
3 2020-06-03  31      1
4 2020-06-04  40      1
5 2020-06-05  51      1
```

**Group 2:**

```
        date val record
1 2020-06-01  10      1
2 2020-06-02  20      1
3 2020-06-03  31      1
4 2020-06-04  40      1
5 2020-06-05  52      2
```

**Group 3:**

```
        date val record
1 2020-06-01  10      1
2 2020-06-02  20      1
3 2020-06-03  32      2
4 2020-06-04  40      1
5 2020-06-05  51      1
```

**Group 4:**

```
        date val record
1 2020-06-01  10      1
2 2020-06-02  20      1
3 2020-06-03  32      2
4 2020-06-04  40      1
5 2020-06-05  52      2
```

**Group 5:**

```
        date val record
1 2020-06-01  10      1
2 2020-06-02  20      1
3 2020-06-03  33      3
4 2020-06-04  40      1
5 2020-06-05  51      1
```

**Group 6:**

```
        date val record
1 2020-06-01  10      1
2 2020-06-02  20      1
3 2020-06-03  33      3
4 2020-06-04  40      1
5 2020-06-05  52      2
```

I've tried the following solution, but it does not produce the desired results.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- consumption %>% 
   filter(n > 1) %>%
    group_split(date, rn = row_number()) %>% 
    map(~ bind_rows(consumption %>%
          filter(n == 1), .x %>%
             select(-rn)) %>% 
         arrange(date))
```

Your help to getting around this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `filter` where the 'record' is greater than 1, `group_split` by 'row_number' and 'date', then bind the rows with the `filter`ed data where the 'record' is 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- consumption %>% 
   filter(n > 1) %>%
    group_split(date, rn = row_number()) %>% 
    map(~ bind_rows(consumption %>%
          filter(n == 1), .x %>%
             select(-rn)) %>% 
         arrange(date))
```

-output

```
> out
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    31     3      1
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    32     3      2
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    33     3      3
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
```

---

With the updated data, we create the `row_number()`, then `split` it by 'date' column (as in @ThomasIsCoding solution), use `crossing` (from `purrr`) to expand the data, and loop over the rows with `pmap`, `slice` the rows of the original data based on the row index

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
consumption %>%
     transmute(date, rn = row_number()) %>%
     deframe %>%
     split(names(.)) %>%
     invoke(crossing, .) %>%
     pmap(~ consumption %>% 
        slice(c(...))) %>%
     unname
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    31     3      1
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    51     2      1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    31     3      1
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    52     2      2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    32     3      2
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    51     2      1

[[4]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    32     3      2
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    52     2      2

[[5]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    33     3      3
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    51     2      1

[[6]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    33     3      3
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    52     2      2
```

Comment: This is perfect... You are a star!!! Saved my day... Thanks heaps!!!
Gosh, I need a training for purrr library.

Comment: This solution breaks down when multiple days have multiple readings for some reason :( i.e. three rows for 2020-06-03 and two rows for 2020-06-05.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
with(
  consumption,
  apply(
    expand.grid(
      split(seq_along(date), date)
    ),
    1,
    function(k) consumption[k, ]
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    31     3      1
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    51     2      1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    32     3      2
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    51     2      1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    33     3      3
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    51     2      1

[[4]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    31     3      1
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    52     2      2

[[5]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    32     3      2
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    52     2      2

[[6]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         val     n record
  <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
1 2020-06-01    10     1      1
2 2020-06-02    20     1      1
3 2020-06-03    33     3      3
4 2020-06-04    40     1      1
5 2020-06-05    52     2      2
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I really wish there is option to grant bounties to more than one people.

Comment: No worries, my friend. I am happy your question got resolved. @M.Qasim

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using some basic `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions.

First, complete the data for every date / copy combination. Then fill the missing ones with the prior value, and reshape wide.

```
library(tidyverse)
consumption %>%
   complete(date, record) %>%
   group_by(date) %>% fill(val) %>% ungroup() %>%
   pivot_wider(-n, names_from = record, values_from = val)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date         `1`   `2`   `3`
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-06-01    10    10    10
2 2020-06-02    20    20    20
3 2020-06-03    31    32    33
4 2020-06-04    40    40    40
5 2020-06-05    51    52    52
```